# Why in unity editor window script when making new Color instance it's not changing to the color?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

```
void DrawItemBackgroundColor(Rect bgRect)
        {
            if (Event.current.type == EventType.Repaint)
            {
                Color oldColor = GUI.color;
                GUI.color = new Color(255, 182, 193);

                var rect = bgRect;
                rect.height = Styles.headerBackground.fixedHeight;
                Styles.headerBackground.Draw(rect, false, false, false, false);

                rect.y += rect.height;
                rect.height = bgRect.height - rect.height;
                Styles.background.Draw(rect, false, false, false, false);

                GUI.color = oldColor;
            }
        }
```

This should change the color to pink :

```
GUI.color = new Color(255, 182, 193);
```

But it does nothing.

But if I'm doing :

```
GUI.color = Color.red;
```

It will change it to red the problem is that Color don't have all the colors only some.

Answer (score 1):

For your case :

```
GUI.color = new Color(255f/255f, 182f/255f, 193f/255f);
```

1. Color RGB value range is 0~1
2. Color32 RGB value range is 0~255

So you can use Color32 by 0~255 or Use Color by 0~1;

Answer (score 0):

Solution is to use Color32 :

```
void DrawItemBackgroundColor(Rect bgRect)
{
    if (Event.current.type == EventType.Repaint)
    {
        Color oldColor = GUI.color; 
        GUI.color = new Color32(255, 182, 193,100);

        var rect = bgRect;
        rect.height = Styles.headerBackground.fixedHeight;
        Styles.headerBackground.Draw(rect, false, false, false, false);

        rect.y += rect.height;
        rect.height = bgRect.height - rect.height;
        Styles.background.Draw(rect, false, false, false, false);

        GUI.color = oldColor;
    }
}
```

This line make it color in nice light pink color :

```
GUI.color = new Color32(255, 182, 193,100);
```

Comment: If you want only the background color you might consider using `GUI.backgroundColor` instead